# How do you preserve hue associations across multiple plots in seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, seaborn

With the following code as an example, how can I preserve the column-colour associations that you see in Plot 1 in the plot below it, Plot 2?

Is there a way to instruct `sns` to 'skip' a hue at specific points? I am looking for a simple workaround that I can control finely, and ideally without manually assigning hex codes.

To be clear, in Plot 2 I would like `'C'` to appear green and `'E'` to appear purple.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(42)

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 5), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

df_2 = df_1.drop(['B', 'D'], axis=1)
```

— Plot 1 —

```
sns.boxplot(data=df_1,
            orient="h")
plt.show()
```

[image]

— Plot 2 —

```
sns.boxplot(data=df_2,
            orient="h")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a dictionary to [`boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)'s `palette`:

```
# all unique keys
keys = df_1.columns.union(df_2.columns).unique()
# or for more dataframes:
# set().union(*(df.columns for df in [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4]))
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

# create key: color dictionary
colors = dict(zip(keys, sns.color_palette('Set1')))

# plot 1
sns.boxplot(data=df_1, orient='h', palette=colors)
# plot 2
sns.boxplot(data=df_2, orient='h', palette=colors)
```

*NB. you can replace `sns.color_palette('Set1')` by a list of colors (e.g. `['#e41a1c', '#377eb8', '#4daf4a', '#984ea3', '#ff7f00']`).*

If you use seaborn's palettes, keep in mind that some are limited in the number of colors. To cycle over them use:

```
import itertools

colors = dict(zip(keys, itertools.cycle(sns.color_palette('Set1'))))
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

```
sns.palplot(colors.values())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution. If you note that `len(sns.color_palette('Set1')) == 9`, how do I handle cases where I am plotting more than 9 keys? When you pass `palette='Set1'` to `sns.boxplot` it just rolls over the colors and starts again. Can `colors` be adjusted to handle this? Or would you look for a palette with more colors?

Comment: If you want to cycle on the colors use: `colors = dict(zip(keys, itertools.cycle(sns.color_palette('Set1'))))`. If you want distinct colors, keep in mind that you cannot have more than a dozen colors and expect an average human to be able to distinguish them unambiguously. That said, you can create palettes with more colors, have a look at the [`color_palette`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html) documentation, for instance `sns.color_palette('hls', 30)` (and see for yourself how some colors are ambiguous!).

Comment: I agree. The real-world problem I am facing is a special case. Thanks for updating the answer!

Comment: "*The real-world problem I am facing is a special case.*" Now I'm curious, can you elaborate? ;)

Comment: Let's just say that I am working with Early Modern English data and spelling hasn't stabilized yet !